# Annotations @NotBlank and @NotNull doesn't work

Tags: java, spring

I've followed several guides to get @NotNull and @NotBlank annotations working but I can't get them to work at all. This is a Spring-Boot project. I inserted these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId> 
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
   <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I entered @Valid inside the controller, importando:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
```

And I used annotations like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    @NotNull(message = "name can't be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "name can't be empty")
```

I tried many solutions but none of them could help me

Comment: You said you used `@Valid` but didn't show it. Are you sure it's in the right place (on the DTO parameter of the resource method)?

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot 3, you need to use the `jakarta.validation` annotations, not `javax.validation`. Also, you should **not** explicitly specify a version for dependencies like `hibernate-validator`, you should use the version specified and managed by Spring Boot

Comment: Remove `hibernate-validator`, remove the `version` from `spring-boot-starter-validation`. If you have any `validation-api` dependency (which I suspect you do) dithc it as well and fix the compilation issues by using the proper `jakarta.validation` imports instead of `javax.validation` imports. (This is all assuming Spring Boot 3.x).

Answer (score 2):

jakarta validation is available in the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Replace

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId> 
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
   <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

with `spring-boot-starter-validation` and make sure that you keep it the same version as your Spring boot, reload your project so that it can pull the new dependencies and drop the hibernate, and after that you can use jakarta imports such as

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Max;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
```

Keep in mind that javax packages worked in Spring boot 2 / Spring 5, after that packages were moved from javax to jakarta in a newer version of the Spring boot / Spring.

Also it would be wise that you define your spring version in your parent tag instead of defining it in every dependency tag individually, it should look something like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

All your spring dependencies will inherit this version, it is easier to maintain and safer to not mix up some versions which can cause issues.

Comment: This was key to my solution 

```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>```

Answer (score 1):

It works! Thanks everyone for the help. For all those who have had the same problem as me, in the post I was advised to:

- Remove hibernate-validator
- Delete the conflicting spring-boot-starter-validation version
- Use import jakarta.validation.constraints and not javax

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with a Spring MVC project I was building.

My entity class looked like this:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    private String title;
```

The controller method was as follows

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String addBook(@Valid @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            bindingResult.getAllErrors().forEach(objectError -> {
                logger.debug(objectError.toString());
            });
            return "books/book-form";
        }
        bookService.addBook(book);
        return "redirect:/books/list";
    }
```

and this key addition to work with my pom file resolved my failing issue:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**In short:**

Spring Boot 3x needs `jakarta.validation.constraints`

Your pom file needs to have

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```